# How to change array of PSCustomObject in Powershell

Tags: powershell

I can modify PSCustomObject property which is Array like:

```
$a.b.c += "new item"
```

Is it possible to do it with function? I mean to pass `$a.b.c` to function and to modify it. Seems that it's not trivial (if possible even): I tried `[ref]` but without success. Only one way which works for me is to return new value and to assign it, but this involve `$a.b.c` expression on both sides of function call which makes line long. I tried also:

```
function AddItem {
  Param(
      $Obj,
      $Value,
      [switch]$Uniq
  )
  $MutObj = [System.Collections.ArrayList]$Obj
  $MutObj.Add($Value) > $null
}
```

but this also does not work, seems that `$a.b.c += x` is actually `change property "c" of $a.b object` and I have not `$a.b` in function scope. Is it achievable even with function and with modification in place in its body?

Comment: can you show me what the PS custom object looks like

Comment: it's decoded JSON file. I tested this function on property which looks like `[ ["aaa", "bbb"], ["ccc", "ddd"]]`. And call it like `AddItem $a.b.c 1` where `$a.b.c` is exactly those array of arrays

Comment: i mean can you post the code that makes the `PSCUSTOMObject`

Comment: This is the code `function Read-Cfg {
    $js = Get-Content -Raw -Path $args[0]
    return ConvertFrom-Json -InputObject $js
}
` This functions returns PSCustomObject with `a.b.c` property which I use to test that function

Comment: This looks like an [X-Y problem](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem). Please take a step back and describe the actual problem you're trying to solve instead of what you perceive as the solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you are asking is why the object doesn't change in the function.

Powershell handles Function variables as Values which means it creates another variable exactly like the one passed in and changes it in scope of the function. What you want to do is make this by Reference meaning it will mess with the same object passed into the function. This is done by the type [Ref] added to the value passed into the parameter. In this example the magic is handled here `Additem -Object ([ref]$JSON) -Value "TEST"`

Full script

```
function AddItem {
  Param(
      $Object,
      $Value,
      [switch]$Uniq
  )
  $Object.Value += $Value
}

$JSON = '[["aaa", "bbb"], ["ccc", "ddd"]]' | ConvertFrom-Json 

Additem -Object ([ref]$JSON) -Value "TEST"

"0  : $($JSON[0])"
"0  : $($JSON[1])"
"0  : $($JSON[2])"
```